# Hide jQuery generated content when CSS :focus is false

Tags: jquery, css

I have a search box which, in it's first start is a magnifying glass icon. When clicked (`:focus`) it expands into a search box where you can type.

A friend of mine helped me with out by writing a jQuery code that when the user starts typing in the search field, results show instantly beneath it (from my mySQL database), which you can click to take you to the result.

However, if you click off the search field, and the CSS is no longer set to `:focus` the jQuery (lets call them) quick results, do not disappear, obviously - as nothing tells them too.

My question is - How can I make them show when the search box is `:focus` on and disappear when it is not.

This is the CSS for the search bar:

```
.search_bar input[type="text"] {
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: -18px;
    padding: 0 0 0 22px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 54px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.search_bar input[type="text"]:focus{
    width: 550px;
    outline: none;
}
```

And this is the CSS for the jQuery results (the space where they generate:

```
#searchResult {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width: 536px;
right: 20px;
top: 40px;  
text-align: left;
}
```

This the the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('#search_bar').keyup(db_search);
    });

    function db_search()
    {
        var searchFor = jQuery('#search_bar').val();
        if (searchFor=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("searchResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","php/searchFor.php?search="+searchFor,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Here is some stills to illustrate my problem, if it is not clear.

[image: This is the un focused search]
[image: This is when <code>:focus</code> is on]
[image: This is the jQuery 'Quick Search' links showing (as they should do)]
[image: This is my problem, when the search box slides back, the results stay, i want to hide them]

I tried to use this CSS to hide it:

```
.search_bar input[type="text"]:focus + #searchResult {
display: block;
}
```

To `display: block` when `:focus` on search bar.

```
#searchResult {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width: 536px;
right: 20px;
top: 40px;  
text-align: left;
display: none;
}
```

To hide the whole div and its content when it's not `:focus` on the search bar.

But this doesn't work and I can't figure out how else I would do it, I still have a very very limited knowledge of jQuery/javascript so if the answer lies in this, could some one be kind enough to share the answer? I tried to research the hide() function in jQuery but I didn't know where to place it, I assume it would be in an if statement?

Sorry for a long question, I tried to be as clear and thorough as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to take a look at the jquery .blur() event: http://api.jquery.com/blur/.

You can try this (untested) code:

```
 jQuery('#search_bar')
     .keyup(db_search)
     .blur(function() { $("#searchResult").hide(); });
```

Explanation: the blur event is called whenever the element loses focus. In this scenario, the user puts the focus on the #search_bar. When the #search_bar has a keyup event, it does the search as you were doing before, but when #search_bar loses focus (the user clicked somewhere else, or on one of the results) the #searchResults are hidden.

Comment: I have given this the correct answer as this code works as do the others, but this has also given me an explanation as to how so I can understand it for myself, and others can benefit when searching for answers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

try to add this to your jQuery code

```
jQuery('.search_bar').blur(function(){
    jQuery('#searchResult').hide();
});
```

Comment: Check your code, search_bar is a class, so the code needs to be $('.search_bar') Actually the CSS shows it as a class and the jQuery code the OP shows has it as an index.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You are correct Jay, I hadn't picked up on this, there is an inconsistency of calling the class in the CSS and HTML but the jQuery shows ID. If I change my jQuery to a class or my CSS/HTML to an ID, it breaks (which is strange). An oversight on mine and my friend who wrote the jQuery's part it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of your jQuery code - (Is search_bar a class like you have in the CSS or is it an id as shown in your jQuery code?)

```
$('.search_bar').blur(function(){
    $('#searchResult').hide();
});
```